# nth-child не работает в ссылках

Tags: html, css

Если оборачивать div ссылкой, то перестает работать nth-child и из-за этого падает последний блок, в чем может быть проблема?

```css
.button
{
 width: 295px;
 height: 60px;
 background-color: #036398;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 60px;
 color: #fff;
 float: left;
 font-size: 25px;
 margin-right: 20px;
 transition: all 1s;
 -webkit-transition: all 1s;
 -moz-transition: all 1s;
 -o-transition: all 1s;
 cursor: pointer;
}
a .button:nth-child(4n+4)
{
 margin-right: 0;
}
.button:hover
{
 background-color: #fff;
 color: #036398;
}
.center2
{
 width: 1240px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="center2">
  <div class="buts">
    <a href="#"><div class="button">1</div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="button">2</div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="button">3</div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="button">4</div></a>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `падает последний блок` - куда он падает? а где он должен быть?

Comment: в место `div` лучше выбрать  `span` так как блочный элемент вставлять в строчный запрещено...

Comment: @Air уже не запрещено

Comment: @МузыкаСергей, уже? Если не секрет, пришли ссылку где ты это прочитал, просто интересно почитать... Не знал...

Comment: @Air https://www.w3.org/TR/html/textlevel-semantics.html#the-a-element
https://habrahabr.ru/company/htmlacademy/blog/336638/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что за ерунда? Вы хотите выбрать каждый четверый блок .button, но он у вас в каждой ссылке только один. Правильная конструкция такая:

```css
.button {
  width: 295px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #036398;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  transition: all 1s;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  -moz-transition: all 1s;
  -o-transition: all 1s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a:nth-child(4n+4) .button {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #036398;
}

.center2 {
  width: 1240px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="center2">
  <div class="buts">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="button">1</div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="button">2</div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="button">3</div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="button">4</div>
    </a>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```